# custom Adapter: why come this java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, custom-adapter

Why I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`
I try many way but still not working...

```
private class LoadAllQoutes extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  List<Quotescategory>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuotesActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading qoutes. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected List<Quotescategory> doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_qoutes, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Qoutes: ", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                QOUTES =json.getJSONArray(TAG_QOUTES);

                for (int i = 0; i < QOUTES.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c =QOUTES.getJSONObject(i);

                    quotescat.setId(c.getString(TAG_QID));
                    quotescat.setName(c.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    quotescat.set_By(c.getString(TAG_BY));
                    listcat.add(quotescat);

                    Log.d("All Qoutes: ", "Add on list");
                    Log.d("All Qoutes2: ", quotescat.getName().toString());

                }
            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                startActivity(i);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Quotescategory> result) { 

       ListView Items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quoteslist);



        QuotesSimpleAdapter adapter=new QuotesSimpleAdapter(local, R.layout.list_item, result);
        Items.setAdapter(adapter);            

    }
}

 public class QuotesSimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter 
 {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Quotescategory> data = null;

    public QuotesSimpleAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceId, List<Quotescategory> result)            {
        super(context,layoutResourceId, result);

        this.context = context;
        this.data = result;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
    }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
   }

   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
   }

    @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RssItemHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {

        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RssItemHolder();

        holder.txt_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_qid);

        holder.txt_by=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_by);

        holder.txt_name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

        row.setTag(holder);


    } else {

        holder = (RssItemHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Quotescategory QItem = data.get(position);
    holder.txt_id.setText(QItem.getId());
    holder.txt_name.setText(QItem.getName());
    holder.txt_by.setText(QItem.get_By());

    return row;
}

static class RssItemHolder {

    TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_name;
    TextView txt_by;
}

}
```

> log cat:

```
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.guajratipride2.QuotesSimpleAdapter.getCount(QuotesSimpleAdapter.java:31)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:454)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.pride.QuotesActivity2$LoadAllQoutes.onPostExecute(QuotesActivity.java:193)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.pride.QuotesActivity2$LoadAllQoutes.onPostExecute(QuotesActivity.java:1)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-08 11:30:48.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: no error in adapter please post the activity code

Comment: which code have you got this error or otherwise post full logcat.

Comment: The stack trace of the exception (the part you did not post) tells you the exact line number where it happens.

Comment: change out and its error come from this part only

Comment: there is error on the List<Quotescategory> result //this result is null so make sure you are setting through custom adapter make sure it contains any value from where it set to the adapter on the main activity

Comment: so hows can I resolve where I set now  it thanks your time give me

Comment: you first check that List have some values before setting to custom adapter on the main activity

Comment: QuotesSimpleAdapter adapter=new QuotesSimpleAdapter(local, R.layout.list_item, result);
        Items.setAdapter(adapter);            
check that result have some values or not before setting to the adapter here check and tell me what is the result actually at that time

Comment: What is `local` here??

Comment: thanks abhishek    and local is activity piyush

Comment: thanks to ALL give your time

Comment: @Ghanshyam feel free to accept the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

> return something(listcat); //instead of null
>   int the doInbackground

Answer (score 1):

You are returning "null " from doInBackground method:

please change this statement to :

```
 return result;
```

(i think you need to pass the listCat here.)

this result is passed to your

```
onPostExecute(List<Quotescategory> result)
```

Hope this is your problem

Answer (score 1):

NPE is caused by Adapter not having proper data. Add a sanity check in your `getCount()` :

```
@Override
public int getCount() { // list should be empty if data is null
    return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
}
```

Also, change your `AsyncTask` doInBackground to return your data for the list :

```
protected List<Quotescategory> doInBackground(String... args) {    
    //.... your code

    return result; // not null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this code,

```
  @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RssItemHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, false);
        holder = new RssItemHolder();

        holder.txt_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_qid);

        holder.txt_by=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_by);

        holder.txt_name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {

        holder = (RssItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Quotescategory QItem = data.get(position);
    holder.txt_id.setText(QItem.getId());
    holder.txt_name.setText(QItem.getName());
    holder.txt_by.setText(QItem.get_By());

    return convertView;
}
```

i think this may help you